# JS - AngularJS - Get data of an directive from a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I´ll give my best to make my problem understandable:

I have a directive. This directive handles/alters also some data it displays. Now I was wondering how I can access these data from a parent scope e.g. the controller. I am currently getting access to the scope by selecting the element and ask for the corresponding scope:

`element.scope()`

It works fine but it occurs to me that this is kind of a - lets say - unconventional or odd way to get the scope of an directive.

I apologize for my english (I still practicing) and hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: could you please tell me more about your directive?Is it an element?How do you initialize it with the data should be displayed?

Comment: You should use scope configuration in your directive.

Comment: The directive is an element. It displays some inputfields the user can use to enter data. When the user has entered all the data I would like to gain access to these data.

Comment: OK,So it's some kind of a form, you can use `controller` in your `return` object in the directive and then, You can directly control all of your models.
should I show you an example?

Comment: That would be ver kind, soroush gholamzadeh

Comment: FYI: The reason why I use a directive here is because the form is dynamically extendable with repeatable sections. So in the end the directive is used multiple times on a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Based on the comments your directive is some kind of a form. There are two approaches for controlling the data inside a directive:

1. **Parent controller of a directive should control the data.** In that case, Data of each directive is unique and does not share between all directives.
2. **The directive itself should control the data.** Which it means the data will be shared in all directives, and if You change one, another will be changed too.

I go with the solution number 1 which is more preferable in my guess. Let's say your template of directive is something like this,We call it `template.html`:

```
<form name="directive_from" ng-submit="submit_form()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.name" name="username" placeholder="username"><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Because of the time,I skipped validation but you can do that easily :)

And the directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('formDirective',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            scope: {
                form: '=formData',
                submit_form: '@formFunc'
            },
            controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
                //some extra logic or binding if you need
            }
        }
})
```

OK,Now our directive which we call it `formDirective` accepts two parameters:

1. `formData` which is an object and holds user inserted data.
2. `formFunc` which is a function for submitting the form.

Now parent controller:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.form_object = {};
        $scope.submit_it = function() {
            //Do whatever you like with the $scope.form_object
        }
    }
```

And let's see the view:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <form-directive form="form_object" form-func="submit_it()"></form-directive>
</div>
```

That's it! It's so simple example that I believe you can customize it by your needs,But the main logic for controlling the data is something like that. for example you can pass a function for `ng-change` on the input field or add more input fields or...

Answer (score 2):

@lilly: I think you you are looking for data exchange between the parent scope and isolated scope which is possible via '='

Here is the working fiddle

```
    angular.module('App', [])
.controller('Main', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.exchange = {};
  $scope.exchange.value = "initialized by controller";
}])


.directive('inputValue', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {exchangeValue: '='},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function(){
                 scope.exchangeValue="changed by directive";
        },2000);  
    }
  };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tiru/dJty6/43/

Comment: thats also very interesting =) thanks for your effort!